# How to display the increment after averaging the total?

Tags: c

I am trying to gather the average of the positive entries, the negative entries and all the entries made.

'''

```
while(num != 0)
{
    if (num > 0)
    {
        positive = positive + num;
        p++;
    }
    else
    {
        negative = negative + num;
        n++;
    }
    count++;
    
    printf("\nEnter the number (Program exit if input is 0):  ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
printf("\nNumber of p Numbers: %d ", p);
printf("\nNumber of n Numbers: %d ", n);

printf("\nNumber of Positive Numbers: %d ", positive);
printf("\nNumber of Negative Numbers: %d ", negative);
printf("\nTotal count: %d", count);

posAvg = positive / p ;
printf("\nNumber of positive average number per count: %f", posAvg);

negAvg = negative / n ;
printf("\nNumber of negative average number per count: %f\n\n", negAvg);

return 0;
```

}
'''

Unfortunately, everytime I gather the result for the average, I always end up with int number instead of float number.

Ex: Enter 4 and 5
Average: 4.0 instead of 4.5.

I put the float on average, but I feel like I'm missing something. Can you assist me this? Thank you.

Comment: You have to cast one of your operands to float so that the result is a float:
posAvg = (float)positive / p;

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as [tag:C]?

Comment: Are you sure this is C#? C# doesn't have things like `printf(...)` and `scanf(...)` so unless you're using a library that specifically reimplements them for C# this looks more like C. That and you're using pointers, which is very uncommon in C#.

Comment: You're correct. It's C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
posAvg = (float)positive / p;
```

Your variable is a float, but the left-hand expression are all int values, so the left-hand will result in an int value, unless you cast one of the operands to a float so the expression operands are all implicitly converted to float.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#numeric-promotions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions